# Can Stack Exchange support the Mozilla Open Badges service?

Tags: feature-request, badges

There's a web site called [Mozilla Open Badges](http://openbadges.org/en-US/) that serves as a clearinghouse for badge issuers and earners. It would be cool if Stack Exchange could support this.

Would this be possible?

A basic introduction to badges (for a badge issuer) can be found [here](http://openbadges.org/en-US/issuer.html), and a technical introduction is [here](https://github.com/mozilla/openbadges/wiki/Issuer-API).

A different possibility is that someone can make a separate site that awards openbadges based on the stackoverflow api - would this be possible?

Comment: Why the down votes?

Comment: Downvote because the emphasis should be on the questions and answers, not those asking or answering.

Answer (score 9):

OpenBadge also provides a feature to upload the badges manually.  But I also agree that it would be nice if StackExchange provides a feature to sync with Mozilla OpenBadges.

I twitted with Mozilla Badge in Twitter (@openbadges).  Their response is as follows

> Thanks for your interest in Open Badges.
>   We're in discussions with them but a little community interest never hurt.

[image: Image : Manual Upload of mozilla OpenBadges]

Comment: I don't have a problem with uploading the badges manually, the problem is the creating the badges - Stack Exchange needs to host stuff here.

Comment: @Inkbug I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

See the ["flair"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/190534/inkbug/flair) page in your profile for a way of displaying your StackExchange prowess on other sites.

Comment: Flair is incompatible with Mozilla Open Badges, so this doesn't help me.

Comment: So your question is actually "Can SO support the Mozilla Open Badges service?" I'll edit it to fit.

Comment: Yes. That's basically what I meant.