# Add direct support for OpenBadges on Careers

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Having asked [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180398/169515), I thought I would follow it up with a suggestion that Careers.SO support open badges directly, whether by importation into the "certifications" section, or by another means (perhaps simply by linking to your Mozilla Backpack account in the same manner as you can link to Github, SourceForge, etc).

Comment: Related (not for Careers specifically, but SE in general): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139553/can-stack-exchange-support-the-mozilla-open-badges-service

Answer (score 5):

Open Badges are pretty new and I know of no open badges that would affect my hiring decision for a candidate.  I also don't care to spend the time researching some particular open badge to see if it should be a valuable signal in the process.  Perhaps eventually one will get there, but for now, not really.

Valuable additions to profiles should be **widely accepted** methods of showing programming ability or depth of technical knowledge and be easily traceable to the person who created the original work.